# PowerShell DSC for client machines?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am trying to use PowerShell DSC to deploy our software to client PCs; in most of the DSC tutorials or examples that I have seen, DSC seems to be used to deploy **server** software.

Does it make sense to use DSC for **client** PCs?

Notes :

- I have already tried deployment with the classic .MSI packages; it doesn't work very well in our case for various reasons, and we would really benefit from the fact that DSC deployments can automatically "heal" in case of problems.
- I use puppet to deploy the server-side software; it works fine, but puppet doesn't seem to be a good fit for client PCs (therefore PowerShell DSC).

Answer (score 0):

DSC does ship in the client. When we say DSC is for configuring servers it means we will target scenarios specific to the server. However, with the existing features if you can solve a scenario in client, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Dsc is oriented for server , where a configuration is global for the system (like a database , web or file server).

Users can have differents settings on the same machine , dsc is not the best solution to deal with that usecase.

Anyway, for package deployment you can look at Oneget or Chovolatey ;)